# split number into group of 3 digits and the rest into 2 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use JavaScript and regex to split 7 digits into one group of 3 digits and the rest into a group of 2 this is the regex 
I have

```
let foo = 1234567; 
foo.match(([\d.]{3})([\d.]{2})([\d.]{2}))
```

I am expecting an array formatted like: `[123,45,67]`

Comment: Is there a reason to use regular expressions at all? I mean, are the parts varying in length, characters, etc? Otherwise, just use simple array functions. If there's some need to use a regular expression, please provide more input strings. As it stands, the question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a positive lookahead and match only groups of three or two.

```js
function split(n) {
    return n.toString().match(/.{2,3}(?=..)|.+/g);
}

console.log(split(1234567));
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have it, you just need to convert the number to a string using `toString()` or `String(foo)`. Then `shift()` the first item off of the list

```js
let foo = 1234567; 
let matches = foo.toString().match(/([\d.]{3})([\d.]{2})([\d.]{2})/)
matches.shift()

// Use `.map(Number)` to convert the values back to numbers
console.log(matches.map(Number))
```

We can also use slice 3 times to grab different sections of the string like this:

```js
let foo = String(1234567)

console.log([
  foo.slice(0,3),
  foo.slice(3,5),
  foo.slice(5,7)
].map(Number))
```

Comment: Well then. It might as well have been me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use match will following regex

```
/^\d{3}|\d{2}|\d+/
```

You can drop off last `\d+` if you want you output contain only group of atleast of two digits in case you have digit like `12345678 => ['123','45','67']`

```js
let foo = 1234567; 

let op = ('' + foo).match(/^\d{3}|\d{2}|\d+/g)

console.log(op)
```